# How to use save() function in R when variable names are stored in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector say varNames which has "name" of certain variables as "character". Now I want to save those particular variables as rdata using save(). How should I go about that?

I was trying to do the following:

```
> varSet
  [1] "blah1"  [2] "blah2"
> str(vatSet)
  chr [1:44] "blah1" "blah2" ...
> foo <- lapply(varSet, function(x) as.name(x))
```

As expected foo is a list of symbols. I was thinking of doing something like

```
eval(unlist(foo), file="fileName")
```

I guess unlist(foo) is not working. How should I solve this issue? Can you also clear my concept why unlist(foo) is not unlisting the list of symbols?

Edit: Adding artificial example

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> y <- data.frame(m=c(1,2), n=c(1,2,3))
```

I can do this to save x and y.

```
> save(x, y, file="filename.rda")
```

But suppose I have

```
> varSet <- c("x", "y")
```

In my example varSet is a very big set. So I need to use varSet to save corresponding variables whose names are stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can save any data object as:

```
save(varSet, file="varSet.RData")
```

But your inquiry sounds a bit confused. Do you want just to save it, or save it in a particular way, like data.frame?

Assuming your list of lists is called varSet:

You can also use a plyr solution:

```
library (plyr)
  df <- ldply(varSet, data.frame)
```

Or more manually strategy. Assuming you list has 100 elements:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(varSet), nrow=100, byrow=T))
```

The above will convert all character columns to factors, to avoid this you can add a parameter to the data.frame() call:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(varSet), nrow=100, byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: save(varSet, filename="something.rda") will save content the variable "varSet" as rdata. However my problem is different. I need to store the variables whose NAMES are stored as STRINGS in varSet. Suppose, varSet[1] = "x". Now, ideally eval(as.name(x)) gives me values of the variable x (not to be confused with character "x"). Hope I am able to clarify my problem.

Comment: Have you did a try on the solution I provided? To be more assertive, I'd see more about you data; give us a reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry. It is not working. I made some edits in the original post and included an example. Please see.

Comment: You example maybe not that helpful. Now you giving a vector character. So , if I understood, you don't want to save the whole bundle, but just some of the elements; did I understand right?

Comment: Yes kind of. Let me put this way. Suppose you are given a list of names of some students.. That's all you have at this stage. Now you go to a classroom and call those students whose names are matching with your list. You are putting those students in a "single" jail. My problem is something similar. I have variable names which are "string". I want to call them and store them.